# New Date By Ticks Not Working (Calculating Next Time Timer Will Fire)

Tags: vb.net, datetime, date, timer, intervals

I am setting a timer interval of (Hours):

```
Timer1.Interval = ((CInt(ComboBox24.SelectedItem.ToString()) * 60 * 60) * 1000)
```

And then calculating the next DateTime that the ticks event will fire using:

```
MessageBox.Show("Next Timer Will Occur At: " & New Date(DateTime.Now.Ticks + Timer1.Interval))
```

Each time I call the MessageBox it shows me that the next event will fire now (Exact date, hour, minute, second).

I can't see where I have gone wrong here as when I simply messagebox'd the calculation it clearly showed separate numbers (ticks) & by a large amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ticks` aren't the same as milliseconds. Use `Date.Now.TotalMilliseconds`. Or, even better, `AddMilliseconds`:

```
MessageBox.Show("Next Timer Will Occur At: " & DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(Timer1.Interval))
```